# Unable to publish EAR in oracle weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: maven, jax-rs, weblogic12c

When I try to publish my EAR , I am getting the below error. Kindly suggest.

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Configurable
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Configurable
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)

I have these two dependencies added in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

Comment: As you can see inspecting these jars, that class isn't included. You can find it in this [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0), but the right version depends on your EAR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the mentioned dependency as well. Also I could see the specified class in the jar which has been downloaded in m2. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have done a maven update? Can you post all your pom.xml?

Comment: yeah i did maven update. I have manually added that jar in the classpath. Then the error gone. But now I have servlet classes in all my projects , those were added to EAR. but still i m getting ClassNotFoundException for those servlet classes. Any idea?

Comment: Try to post your pom.xml, if possible. When you inspect your EAR, do you see all your library include in the correct path?